# realm - best way to sync data on Azure

Tags: swift, database, azure, realm

I have developed an iOS app with Swift, and now I would like to store data in a database, but I'm not sure about the best way to do it.

1 - First, I thought to convert the realm file stored in the device (iPad) in JSON, then create a web service to manage this JSON and store data in a SQL Database

2 - Realm proposes a solution : Realm Mobile Platform (or Realm Object Server ?). When I read the documentation, it seems to be a really good solution, as the sync is done automatically, and I have nothing to do :). But I see 2 issues. First, is it possible to use and manage the data stored, as in an SQL database, or MySQL ??? And I thought to use Azure (with IIS Server). Can I install Realm on Azure, even if Realm can be installed only on Ubuntu and Mac OS ?

3 - Any other solutions ? :)

Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: Have a look at Azure Mobile App Service or possibly DocumentDb if you want to write your own backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this a lot of ways (of course) in Azure.

**a.** you can use an [Azure Mobile App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/mobile/) which offers a lot of functionality for you including [offline sync data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync) which is part of what you are looking for here. There is also a lot of getting started samples, [including one for iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started).

**b.** if you want to run Realm on Azure that is absolutely possible. Just [create a VM with Ubuntu on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-quick-create-portal) and then install Realm on that machine.

**c.** if you are not worried about offline syncing data or conflict handling in data and just want a light-weight solution to store data in document format then either [Azure Storage Tables](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-ios) or Azure DocumentDB could offer a simple solution. Azure table storage might be easier for your iOS application as it offers a ready made cocoapod for accessing Azure storage accounts.

If you are not determined to use Realm or have any specific requirement that Mobile App Services can't fulfill, I would recommend using Mobile App Services as it is a PaaS offering and would mean a lot less maintenance than running your own VM and monitoring a Realm installation on that.

Comment: up vote
0
down vote
accept
Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm looking at Azure Mobile App Service to see how it works to sync with Realm. I think it is the best solution, but I'm just afraid of how I will do that. Indeed, according to the tuto, some configurations and development need to be done. Is it something complicated ? :)

I will try this, and if I have too many issues, maybe I'll try to install Realm Object Server on a WM.

Comment: Happy to help! If you design your Mobile App Service data model after your Realm data model and that model isn't complex (i.e. you can flatten it or make a tree of it) you should be able to use the built in offline sync feature in Mobile App Services without much effort. I haven't found any iOS lib or pods for Realm to Azure Mobile App Services, but if you do find any (or build it) please share it :).